# How to "sync" 2 angularJS apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I'm developping 2 different AngularJS applications that will run on 2 different devices, but to be used in the same local network.

I have a backend, and both apps can communicate to the backend via a REST API, using Internet.

Now, how to make an app "aware" of what's going on on this other app? I don't know if the correct vocabulary is "notifications" or "events listener" or whatever.

But Let's take an example:

- I push a button on app1 then app2 code is called (in a very short time) (app2 receive and use information sent by app1).

Any idea on how to set a system like this on AngularJS?
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you look at the html5 event listener http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: Have you checked WebSockets?

Comment: Websockets are kind of outdated since html5 but if you plan to make compatible with older browser then yes it is a good solution

Comment: @sam Thanks for SSE idea. I just read an article on SSE and websockets. They say that Websocket is bidirectionnal unlike SSE. Since I need to make app1->server then server->app1, I guess I should look to websocket, should I?

Comment: Another question: Must I use the server? Can I open a socket between my both apps? (because if internet connection is down, it's better for me if apps can talks using local network)